# Why doesn't my jQuery.getJson() fail to work properly to get JSON object from PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have the following JS code in an attempt to retrieve a JSON object from a PHP script as follows:

```
var url="http://lewspage.hostei.com/xword_php/getXword.php";
        jQuery.getJSON(url, {name:title}, function(data) {
        // ... handle response as above
            console.log("Data is "+data);
        });
```

However, when I execute the code in google chrome with title = "P2" and check the console, it does not log anything or print out any eror message, which means getJSON fails.When I try to run the link http://lewspage.hostei.com/xword_php/getXword.php?name=P2 manually, I get the response :

```
{"currentPuzzle":[{"name":"P2","tiles":"327M,328U,329T,330H,331E,332F,333U,334C,335K,336A"}]}
```

which is a valid JSON object.

My PHP script is as follows:

```
<?php

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Obtain username
$name = $_GET["name"];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM CrossWordPuzzles where PuzzleName = '$name'";

$result = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query($sql));

$response["currentPuzzle"]=array();

$puzzle=array();
$puzzle["name"]=$result[1];
$puzzle["tiles"]=$result[2];
array_push($response["currentPuzzle"], $puzzle);


    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);


?>
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: The first thing you have to do is to add error handling to your code using  `.fail`: [jQuery.getJSON(): Examples](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/#entry-examples)

Comment: You or your hoster injects statistic code to the end of the output: `<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code --><script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script><!-- End Of Analytics Code -->` because of that the response is not a valid JSON string. An additional note: `where PuzzleName = '$name'"` is a really bad idea, because someone can manipulate the sql query to expose other data.

Comment: You have to add a JSON header to the PHP script: `header('Content-Type: application/json');`